Find the maximum number of subsets of A that can be chosen such that the intersection of any two distinct subsets has exactly 2019 elements.
the problem
.Consider the set A = {1, 2, . . . , 2021}. The maximum number of subsets of A that can be
chosen such that the intersection of any two distinct subsets has exactly 2019 elements is...?
my idea
If it helps I know that the answer is 2021.
I thought that we should take all the subsets with 2020 elements. Any of their intersection would have 2019 elements so that the requirement would be respected, but I don't know how I would prove that this variant is the one that brings us the maximum number of subsets...

Sketch: if any of your sets had $<2019$ elements, the thing would be impossible.  And, if one of your sets had exactly $2019$ elements, then you'd need all the other subsets to contain that one.

Note:  Not sure what you mean by "subsets with $2020$".  If you mean "subsets with at least $2020$ elements" then I agree.

@lulu I edited my post, sorry

Still not clear.  Do you mean exactly $2020$ or at least $2020$?  Note: if the problem statement were edited to refer to proper subsets only, then the ambiguity doesn't matter.

@lulu I meant exactly 2020 elements, because if we get the one with 2021 elements, ww will actually take A and all the intersection with A and other subset with 2020 elements, will have 2020 elements...is my idea right?

Good point, since the problem does insist on the intersections containing exactly $2019$ elements.  In that case, my initial hint (once fleshed out)  essentially completes the proof.

We denote by $\cal{S}$ the collection of subsets of $\{1,2, \ldots, 2021\}$ such that the pairwise intersection of any two sets in $\cal{S}$ has exactly $2019$ elements.

All subsets in $\cal{S}$ must have at least $2019$ element.

If you have a subset $S$ with exactly $2019$ elements in $\cal{S}$, then every other subset of $\{1,2,\ldots, 2021\}$ in $\cal{S}$ has to contain $S$. That leaves at most $3$ other subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots, 2021\}$ in $\cal{S}$.

If $\{1,2,\ldots, 2021\}$ is in the collection $\cal{S}$, there every other subset in $\cal{S}$ must have exactly $2019$ elements. See 2.

So that leaves the collection $\cal{S}$ to consist entirely of subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots, 2021\}$ with exactly $2020$ elements. Note that the intersection of any such $2$ subsets has exactly $2019$ elements, and that there are exactly $2021$ subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots, 2021\}$ with exactly $2020$ elements.  So set $\cal{S}$ to be the collection of all subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots, 2021\}$ with exactly $2020$ elements.


